# Was some form of "kids" an epithet for political leaders during the Bosnian civil war?

Tags: political-history, bosnian-war

I just read Zlata Filipovich's moving diary from the Bosnian war in French translation.

Often, when referring (I infer) to the political leaders and negotiators, she calls them our "chers bambins", which is something like "dear little munchkins" or "gentle bambinos". The term is loaded with irony because she complains of how the average person's fate is their plaything.

An example in English can be found [on pp. 145-6, in the entry for May 4, 1993](https://archive.org/details/zlatasdiarychil00fili/page/144/mode/2up). There that edition translates the phrase as "kids":

> Those "kids" really are playing around with us. Ordinary people don't want this division—not the Serbs, not the Croats, not the Muslims. ... Politics asks only its own people.

Was this (in whatever its original Bosnian might be) a widespread epithet at the time? Or is it an allusion to something in history or literature? Or did she just invent it?

Comment: "A chicken in every pot, and a comment for every downvote!"

Comment: Can you cite a specific occurrence of this phrase? Someone with access to the original text might then be able to directly compare it to your French translation. A little context is always useful in determining meaning.

Comment: @justCal Good idea; done (in English).

Comment: The only thing better than a little context is a *lot* of context.

Answer (score 3):

I can answer one aspect of your question, *Or did she just invent it?* with a quote from the book version you linked (*thank you for the archive.org link*). From page 28 (all emphasis mine):

> On March 4 (Wednesday) the barricades were re- moved, the "kids" [**a
> popular term for politicians**] had come to some agreement. Great?!

This implies that the phrase was something she heard on a regular basis, and she did not 'invent' it.

She does expand on the theme quite effectively in several other locations within the diary:

p. [103](https://archive.org/details/zlatasdiarychil00fili/page/103/mode/1up?view=theater&q=kids)

> The **"kids" really are *playing***, which is why us kids are not playing,
> we are living in fear, we are suffer- ing, we are not enjoying the sun
> and flowers, we are not enjoying our childhood. WE ARE CRYING.

[pg 114](https://archive.org/details/zlatasdiarychil00fili/page/114/mode/1up?view=theater&q=kids).

> ...this winter, the shortage of wood and food, brings me back to
> earth and then I realize that the war is still on. Why? Why on earth
> don't those **"kids''** come to some agreement? **They really are
> *playing games***. And it's us they're ***playing*** with.

[pg 129](https://archive.org/details/zlatasdiarychil00fili/page/129/mode/1up?view=theater&q=kids).

> The convoy has fallen through. I think we'll have to give up on it.
> You can't get out of Sarajevo. Thy won't let you. Who won't? It
> doesn't even matter . . . We'll stay where we are. This can't go on
> forever. Perhaps the **"kids" will get tired of their *game***. Your
> Zlata

[pg 177](https://archive.org/details/zlatasdiarychil00fili/page/177/mode/1up?view=theater&q=kids).

> Today some Italian journalists asked me what I thought about the idea
> of "Sarajevo — an Open City." I gave them some answer, but I think the
> **"kids" are just *playing*** and I don't believe them at all and I've had enough of everything. Because, I know there is no electricity, no
> water, no food, that people keep getting killed...

and maybe the most effective comparison on [pg. 179](https://archive.org/details/zlatasdiarychil00fili/page/178/mode/1up?view=theater&q=kids):

> The political situation? A STUPID MESS. Maybe that's why everybody is
> so edgy. The "kids" are trying to come to some agreement again.
> They're **drawing maps, *coloring with their crayons***, but I think
> they're crossing out human beings, childhood and everything that's
> nice and normal. **They really are *just like kids***.

So the original entry on page 28 tells us that this was a phrase she heard used locally on a regular basis, and the author quite effectively carries out the comparison throughout the work.

(I have not been able to get any other searches into the term to get past the mass of general material on the war and the crimes and atrocities committed.)

Comment: Ahh, nice. I see now that my edition was abridged / selected and is missing some of these entries, including that crucial footnote in the first one you cited.